# How do I exclude stl files from debugging in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, stl

For some reason Xcode sometimes steps into C++ stl files even when I've chosen to step over a method. This can become really tiresome and slow down the debugging process. Does anyone have advice on how to setup Xcode to not step into stl files? Or to just exclude them from debugging?

Comment: I think it is caused by inline functions, it is actually "step over" in terms of what debugger see.